# Postgresql recheck performed even there are no lossy blocks

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a `explain (buffers, analyze, verbose)`

And I am getting this subresult

```
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.d  (cost=109.92..8479.81 rows=5871 width=40) (actual time=1.334..29.942 rows=5306 loops=1)
    Output: d.id, d.pd, d.iid, d.dtid, d.bid
    Recheck Cond: ((d.sid = 100) AND (d.pd >= '2020-01-28 10:24:40.034+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (d.pd <= '2020-04-28 10:24:40.034+00'::timestamp with time zone))
    Heap Blocks: exact=2014
    Buffers: shared hit=3 read=2035
    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_d_didpd  (cost=0.00..108.45 rows=5871 width=0) (actual time=1.018..1.018 rows=5306 loops=1)
          Index Cond: ((d.sid = 100) AND (d.pd >= '2020-01-28 10:24:40.034+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (d.pd <= '2020-04-28 10:24:40.034+00'::timestamp with time zone))
          Buffers: shared read=24
```

What I am wondering that in whole result the most "costly" parts are that are performing the Bitman Heap Scan (other parts performing the index scan and they are pretty fast). But I´ve read that recheck on bitmap heap scan is performed just in case that there are some `lossy blocks`. Which I can not see here.

Can anyone tell me why is this Heap Scan performed?

Comment: Because Postgres has calculated that a bit map heap scan is the optimal execution path.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for your answer. But why? This operation seems to be really expensive. And there are "just" +- 6000 rows that should be easily handled by index, or Am I wrong? Thats why I am trying to limit the data by some time interval because the d and dt tables are pretty big and therefore query result (without cache) is returned in the interval of higher seconds. Next query is returned pretty fast but thats not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Note that "Recheck Cond" is also present with just an EXPLAIN without the ANALYZE. The value of this field does not depend on what actually happened during execution. It is telling you what condition will be used in a potential recheck, it does not tell you how often the recheck was actually performed (which in your case was probably zero).

> Can anyone tell me why is this Heap Scan performed?

The Bitmap Heap Scan is not just there to do a recheck, its main purpose is to fetch the data you asked for.